# How to set colors in OS X (Mavericks) terminal?

Tags: macos, mac, vim, terminal, colors

I want to set the color's palette of my terminal in order to use properly the Solarized colorscheme for Vim (http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized). I understand that i've to modify my `.bash_profile` but how? (I also installed https://github.com/amix/vimrc which provide some very cool stuff for Vim)

Answer (score 1):

Use either of the two scripts from [this repository](https://github.com/tomislav/osx-terminal.app-colors-solarized) or adjust Terminal.app's default colors manually.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install [Vim Solarized](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized), in this repository they have the instructions.

Move solarized.vim to your .vim/colors directory. After downloading the vim script or package:

```
$ cd vim-colors-solarized/colors
$ mv solarized.vim ~/.vim/colors/
```

Modify ~/.vimrc

```
syntax enable
set background=dark
colorscheme solarized
```

Basically you need to download, and edit your .vimrc in the home folder, if you don't have this file, you just need to create a empty file and edit following the instructions above.

Any doubts please check [Installation](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized#installation)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I use and recommend [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/)

> iTerm2 is a replacement for Terminal and the successor to iTerm. It works on Macs with OS 10.5 (Leopard) or newer. Its focus is on performance, internationalization, and supporting innovative features that make your life better.